# how to insert the date and time with a shortcut in textmate?

Tags: textmate

I would like to insert the current date and time pressing a single key shortcut in TextMate. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For date type `isoD` and then hit `tab` to insert an ISO date.  This is [documented here](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles#tab_triggers).  This is a "snippet" that is part of the "Text" bundle.

To see how this snippet works, hit Ctrl-Opt-Cmd S, expand Text, and select Current Date.  You'll see that it is simply shelling out to the Unix `date` command.  You can control the output format by modifying the existing format string or by creating your own snippet with a custom format string.

See the [date(1) man page](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/freebsd/man1/date.1.html) for usage info and [strftime(3)](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/freebsd/man3/strftime.3.html) for details on the format string.

E.g., for both date AND time, you could use

```
`date "+%D %T"`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Text -> Execute Line and Replace with Result** then select the `/bin/date` utility (enter **date** in the box). Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> should replace the current line with the date. If you'd like it formatted a specific way with the time, you can use a shell script that utilizes `/bin/date` and bind your shortcut to that.